# Inacessible boot device after ubuntu install

Tags: boot, windows, dell

I have bought a Dell XPS 13 with Windows 10 and I decided to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. In order to do it, following an article, I set the kard drive from RAID to AHCI.
Then, I installed Ubunti from a Live usb as I have already done many times.
Ubuntu was installed correctly, but now I cannot access Windows anymore: I receive and errore message "Inaccessible boot device".
If I run lsblk I obtain
 
`NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0  54,7M  1 loop /snap/core18/1668
loop1         7:1    0  44,9M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
loop2         7:2    0 160,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
loop3         7:3    0  89,1M  1 loop /snap/core/8268
loop4         7:4    0  54,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1223
loop5         7:5    0  14,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/399
loop6         7:6    0   956K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/81
loop7         7:7    0  89,1M  1 loop /snap/core/7917
loop8         7:8    0  14,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/317
loop9         7:9    0 149,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
loop10        7:10   0   4,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/501
loop11        7:11   0  44,2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
loop12        7:12   0   4,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/544
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   180M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   128M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 357,9G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   990M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0    13G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0   1,4G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p7 259:7    0 103,5G  0 part /`

I already tried a couple of things, such as updating grub, but I cannot still access to Windows.
Do you have any suggestions?
Best Regards,
Marco

Comment: Editing the drive mode in the bios can cause this. Did you try changing it back to RAID from AHCI?

Comment: I haven't yet tried, but I can. Will it affect the ubuntu installation?

Comment: It won't destroy it but Ubuntu may become unbootable in raid mode.